# how to modify the text of a button if it meets certain expectations?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX I made a grid that 5X5. I want it so that when a user clicks on a button it checks if the string begins with a. If it does, I want to change the text to just an "X". It does nothing otherwise. To build the grid I used one button assignment. what I have now works only if the last button added starts with an a. Would I just have to make each button individually to do this or is there another way?

how gid is made ps board is a previously made string[][]

```
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
        word = new Button(board[i][j]);
        grid.add(word, i, j);
    }
}
private class MouseClickedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String text = word.getText();
        if (text.charAt(0) == 'A' || text.charAt(0) == 'a') {
           word.setText("X");
        }       
    }
```

Comment: You should be able to do something like `Button tempButton = ((Button)arg0.getSource()); if(tempButton.getText().toLowerCase().startWith("a")){tempButton.setText("X");}` This code could be off because I typed it without using and IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to conditionally perform an action for a button:

1. Define an action handler for the buttons.
2. In the action handler, test to see if the required conditions are met.
3. If the test passes, perform the required action.

**Short example**

```
final Button button = new Button(word);
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    if (isRequiredWord(word)) {
        button.setText(MATCHED_VALUE);
    }
});
```

**Sample application**

Display a grid of buttons with words on them.  If the user clicks a button with a word that starts with a letter "a", case insensitive, the button text changes from the displayed word to "X".

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MatchingGameApp extends Application {
    private static final String MATCHED_VALUE = "X";
    private static final String[][] animalBoard = {
            { "cat", "ape" },
            { "aardvark", "dog" }
    };

    /**
     * Add actionable buttons to a grid.
     *
     * @param board A 2D array of words.
     * @param grid a GridPane to which buttons for each word will be added.
     */
    private void addButtons(String[][] board, GridPane grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                final String word = board[i][j];

                final Button button = new Button(word);
                button.setPrefWidth(80);
                button.setOnAction(e -> {
                    if (isRequiredWord(word)) {
                        button.setText(MATCHED_VALUE);
                    }
                });

                grid.add(button, i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A required word is any word starting with a letter "a" in any case.
     */
    public boolean isRequiredWord(String word) {
        return word != null && !word.isEmpty() &&
                word
                        .substring(0, 1)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith("a");
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane layout = new GridPane(10, 10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        addButtons(animalBoard, layout);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to show this example using an `EventHandler` variable, so I altered @jewelsea code.

### Short Code

```
final EventHandler<ActionEvent> buttonActionEventnHandler =
        (actionEvent) -> 
        {
            Button tempButton = (Button)actionEvent.getSource();
            
            if (isRequiredWord(tempButton.getText())) 
            {
                tempButton.setText(MATCHED_VALUE);
            }
        };
```

### Full Code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    private static final String MATCHED_VALUE = "X";
    private static final String[][] animalBoard = {
            { "cat", "ape" },
            { "aardvark", "dog" }
    };

    /**
     * Add actionable buttons to a grid.
     *
     * @param board A 2D array of words.
     * @param grid a GridPane to which buttons for each word will be added.
     */
    private void addButtons(String[][] board, GridPane grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                final String word = board[i][j];

                final Button button = new Button(word);
                button.setPrefWidth(80);
                button.setOnAction(buttonActionEventnHandler);

                grid.add(button, i, j);
            }
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane layout = new GridPane(10, 10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        addButtons(animalBoard, layout);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
    final EventHandler<ActionEvent> buttonActionEventnHandler =
        (actionEvent) -> 
        {
            Button tempButton = (Button)actionEvent.getSource();
            
            if (isRequiredWord(tempButton.getText())) 
            {
                tempButton.setText(MATCHED_VALUE);
            }
        };

    /**
     * A required word is any word starting with a letter "a" in any case.
     * @param word
     * @return 
     */
    public boolean isRequiredWord(String word) {
        return word != null && !word.isEmpty() &&
                word
                        .substring(0, 1)
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith("a");
    }
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I was curious if this code would work for programmatically fired events in addition to user-triggered events.  It did.  After placing either of the following lines after `stage.show()`, the program still treated the appropriate button as the source of the event: `((Button) layout.getChildren().get(1)).fire();` OR `((Button) layout.getChildren().get(1)).fireEvent(new ActionEvent());`.  So the solution is more robust than I thought it might have been.